# Docker-compose with WSL 2 React app not hot reloading on changes

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, docker-compose, dockerfile

My React app isn't reloading on Docker for Windows with docker-compose and WSL2.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./github-finder-app
    volumes:
      - '/var/app/node_modules'
      - './github-finder-app:/var/app'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    command: npm start
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM node:14.9

WORKDIR /var/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install --only=prod
 
EXPOSE 3000
```

Been trying to play around with Chokidar, .env file and different Dockerfiles so far.

Comment: Can you try the solution mentioned here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576659/how-to-hot-reload-in-reactjs-docker
think environment variable is mentioned differently.

Comment: I am having error : `services.frontend.environment.0 must be a string`

Comment: from the code snippet provided in question, you are passing it as Boolean. Can you try passing is as string as mentioned in the link provided in my earlier comment?
environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebPack packaging tool, by the way Hot Module Reload is not using on production in most case(Compact bundle will be running).
"HMR is not intended for use in production, meaning it should only be used in development. See the building for production guide for more information."

Reference: https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/

Comment: Can I use WebPack packaging tool to have auto reload?

Comment: You can use `webpack-dev-server` for more info check these links; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089785/webpack-watch-vs-hot-whats-the-difference,  https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/#in-the-application